# How to print a list element by element vertically? Racket

Tags: list, scheme, racket

Im a noob in Racket, and I am trying to figure out how to print the elements of one list vertically, thus:

> (printv '(1 2 3 4))

1

2

3

4

T

I try with if and cond, thus:

```
(define (delete x lst)
  (cond [(member x lst)(append(reverse(rest(member x(reverse lst))))(rest(member x lst)))]
        [else "Error"]
  ))


    (define (printv lst)
      (cond [(< 0 (length lst)) ((printf "~a ~%" (first lst))(printv (delete (first lst) lst)))]
            [else "T"]))
```

But I got this error in the moment the list becomes empty

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #<void>
  arguments...:
```

Help is appreciated

Comment: `(begin (for-each (lambda (elem) (display elem) (newline)) lst) (display #\T) (newline))`?

Comment: Than you, its works :) but, Do you have any idea why I get an error when reaching '() in my code?

Comment: No idea. I didn't look at your code long enough to attempt to figure out what it's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use built-in procedures to make your life easier. And why do you want to delete the elements? just iterate over the list. Try this:

```
(define (printv lst)
  (for-each displayln lst)
  (displayln "T"))
```

Comment: Thankyou!, I dont know the function "for-each"

Answer (score 1):

Just removing the extra parentheses fixes your problem:

```
(define (printv lst)
  (cond [(< 0 (length lst)) 
         (printf "~a ~%" (first lst))
         (printv (delete (first lst) lst))]
        [else "T"]))
```

Some hints:

Doing `length` at each iteration makes makes your function exponential time. Eg. doubling the list to display squares the time it takes. A beter approach to check if a list is empty is using `(empty? lst)`

How you get the `rest` of the list using `delete` is perhaps the most complicated I've seen. Since you know you are removing the first element you can just replace it with `(rest lst)`.

Just printing with a linefeed has a function: `displayln`

All combined:

```
(define (printv lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) "T"]
        [else 
         (displayln (first lst))
         (printv (rest lst))]))
```

Pure Scheme version:

```
(define (printv lst)
  (cond [(null? lst) "T"]
        [else 
         (display (car lst))
         (newline)
         (printv (cdr lst))]))
```